# How to detect the presence of app in universal Windows plateform

Tags: windows, win-universal-app

I try to find a way to detect dynamically if an app is installed on a computer inside of another UWP. Is there a way to access user app list or is there a workaround ?

Comment: If the app you are looking for supports a file extension or protocol (and presumably it does, otherwise how would you be able to launch it?) you can use Windows.System.Launcher.FindXxxHandlersAsync.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the other app's URI to detect it.

Here's an article I found from 2015 that discusses it.

- http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/6f0898/inter-app-communications-in-windows-10-uwp535/

Let me know if that doesn't work for some reason or if you need newer info, then I do some more digging to provide more info.

All the best!